# Is there a connection between shy (adj.) and shy (v.) meaning throw?

Tags: etymology, british-english, colloquialisms

Most British people probably best recognise the colloquial meaning of shy from the traditional fairground throwing game called the coconut shy but it is also occasionally used in everyday English.

According to the Online Etymological Dictionary the *throw* meaning is the more recent (1787) and a connection between the two is uncertain.  If there is no connection, how did this meaning of shy originate?

Comment: I don't know if "most people" would recognize the phrase "coconut shy". I'd never heard it before and had to look it up. Is this a regional thing?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shy

Comment: Monty Python notwithstanding, I seriously doubt the English had much exposure to coconuts before the modern era.

Comment: @choster: [*cocoa-nut shy*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=jEMAAAAAQAAJ&q=%22nut+shie%22+OR+%22nut+shy%22&dq=%22nut+shie%22+OR+%22nut+shy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9NYiT-ihFaOK4gTK59jyBw&redir_esc=y) possibly dates back to 1884: *"The origin of the now neglected game of " Aunt Sally," also an importation from the tropics, may be attributed to the cocoa-nut ; and at any rate the cocoa-nut "shy" has superseded it by providing not only for the amusement, ..."*

Comment: @Jay: NGram suggests "coconut shy" is [far more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coconut+shy&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) in UK than US English (the "prevalence" percentage has an extra leading zero when you switch corpus from British to American). I'm somewhat surprised to see it barely existed at all before the 1920s.

Comment: @Hugo 1884 is firmly in the modern era.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the *cocoa-nut shy* 'had nearly superseded the more ancient "cock shies"' by [1884](http://books.google.fi/books?id=jEMAAAAAQAAJ&q=%22nut+shie%22+OR+%22nut+shy%22&dq=%22nut+shie%22+OR+%22nut+shy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9NYiT-ihFaOK4gTK59jyBw&redir_esc=y):

[image]

The [17](http://socserv2.mcmaster.ca./%7Eecon/ugcm/3ll3/bentham/usury)[87](http://www.archive.org/stream/defenceusuryshe00bentgoog#page/n178/mode/2up/search/blind) citation from the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shy&allowed_in_frame=0) is from Jeremy Bentham's *Defence of Usury*:

> All that he knows, all
> that he can know, is, that the enterprize is a project, which,
> merely because it is susceptible of that obnoxious name, he looks
> upon as a sort of cock, for him, in childish wantonness, **to shie
> at**.

One [1815](http://books.google.fi/books?id=sygoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22cock+shy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OdgiT6bfOZH14QTvy9jzBw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=shy&f=false) account says normally "a snuff-box, a slice of ginger-bread, or a penny-piece will suffice", but describes the brutal game of a group of sailors in France throwing stones at a live cock on top of a six foot pole.

[image]

Apparently it was an ancient Shrovetide custom to play games outside, and one such game was putting a cock on a pole and killing them with thrown short sticks. From [1837](http://books.google.fi/books?id=LSYaAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA169&dq=%22cock%20shy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=79kiT9j8FMb04QThmoipCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=shy&f=false):

> Shrovetide was in these countries long infamous for the barbarous massacre of cocks, which, at that season, were fastened to a stake, and thrown at with cudgels till their limbs were broken in detail (as, of old, those of the felon were on the wheel), and their bodies "reduced to a jelly." This custom has given origin to a term sacred in the school-boy jargon of old England, where every object set up as a mark for a stone is *pueriliter vocatus* " **a cock-shy**." It is not, perhaps, impossible that from this ancient usage was derived the custom of calling together the Parliament sometime about Shrovetide, on which occasion his majesty's minister for the time being is set up to be flung at by his majesty's opposition *usque ad delicias* Votorum; and thus, the said minister, though seldom entitled to be considered as a ***shy cock***, is made a ***cock-shy*** to all the malcontents in the kingdom.

It's not certain, but this possibly links a timid, scared, *shy* cock to the act of throwing and the coconut *shy*. In any case, all the verb meanings of the word I found are in connection to *throwing at cocks*, as this game was also known. (Hackwood's [1907](http://www.archive.org/details/oldenglishsports00hackrich) *Old English Sports* has a whole chapter on its history and its links to Shrove Tuesday.)

From *The Critical Review*, [1780](http://books.google.fi/books?id=TMMPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA160&dq=cock%20shies&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jM4jT7-QD-Tj4QSXwqykCQ&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=shying%20OR%20shy%20OR%20jbying&f=false) (excerpting *Account of a Debate in Coachmaker's Hall* by Harum Skarum Esq., also 1780):

> ... but me'thinks I knows about ***shying* at cocks** *as much as he*. I remember what monstrous good fun we had last Shrove Tuesday in our lane. My heart! what *fun* it was! Why we ***shy'd* down all the cocks** in the neighbourhood.
>
> ... I do love ***shying* at cocks**, that I do, because it is *such fun*. And what business has the Pope with my cocks ? **I'll shy at 'em** for all him, that I will."

*A New Review*, [1782](http://books.google.fi/books?id=2PwvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA478&dq=cock%20shies&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jM4jT7-QD-Tj4QSXwqykCQ&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=shying&f=false):

> I have been with Dick Brisk **shying at his cock**.

The verb *shy* definition in *The Routledge Dictionary of Historical Slang* by Eric Partridge ([1973](http://books.google.fi/books?id=0voNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=cock%20throwing%20shy&source=bl&ots=b7Fp8WOOQ9&sig=o-pKD7Reddaz-azADcUN2ZmHvc0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tc0jT4yeOfP14QTE8aGkCQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=shy&f=false)) quotes Bentham's 1787 and says it's perhaps an example of *shy(-)cock*, itself defined:

> **shy(-)cock.** A wary person, esp. one who keeps indoors to avoid the bailiffs: 1768, Goldsmith. 2. Hence, a cowardly person: 1796, F. Reynolds. Both senses by ca 1850, the latest record being of 1828. Prob. ex lit. sense, a cock not easily caught, one that will not fight.

(The first meaning can be found in Grose's [1785](http://books.google.fi/books?id=NqHteIy-lXYC&pg=PT181&dq=shying%20cudgels&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zS4lT6qJBOPj4QTRgpn6DA&ved=0CDQQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=shy&f=false) *A Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue*.)

Finally, John Ayto's 1990 *Dictionary of Word Origins* says:

> It is generally assumed that *shy* 'throw' [18th century] must have come from it [the 'timid', 'reserved' meaning], but the exact nature of the relationship between the two words is not clear. The original application of the verb seems to have been specifically to the throwing of sticks at chicken and it has been suggested, not altogether convincingly, that its use alludes to the notion of a 'shy' cockerel that refusese to fight (there was an 18th- and early 19th-century slang term *shy-cock* which meant cowardly person.

Answer (score 0):

Per @JeffSahol's comment link to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shy), origin of "shy" meaning *fling, throw* is uncertain.

The other senses derive from Old English "sceoh" *(timid)*, which also gives rise to the transitive/intransive verb forms whereby a sudden action/sound might [shy the horses](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Dtil4UcN7VQC&pg=PA111&dq=%22shy%20the%20horses%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9NIiT8KqAYij8gPD0NTPBw&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22shy%20the%20horses%22&f=false) (in which case one might say [the horses shied](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=c5A6rs8NP64C&q=%22the%20horses%20shied%22&dq=%22the%20horses%20shied%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=I9UiT8f1LM6X8gOwh-HNBw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA)). Personally, I don't see a huge leap from suddenly *flinging* something to *startling* a timid animal; maybe they really do share common origin, even if the etyomologiest are unable to prove this.